# Visual Studio C++ UWP apps won't write to files under any circumstances

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp, file-io

I am creating a Universal Windows Platform app with C++ that I need to create and write to files from. I was not able to read any files without adding them to the solution and changing their properties to set them as text files that could be referenced. When trying to write to files, even those files do not work. Both of these examples fail to open the file and print "cannot open file" when in any visual studio C++ UWP app.

With fopen:

```
//_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS included in preprocessor
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void VMatrix::SaveFile(string _fileName) 
{
FILE* filepoint;

    if ((filepoint = fopen("fileName.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        // File could not be opened. filepoint was set to NULL
        // error code was stored in errno.
        // error message can be retrieved with strerror(err);
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file '%s': %s\n",
            "fileName.txt", strerror(errno));
    }
    else {
        // File was opened, filepoint can be used to read the stream.
        fclose(filepoint);
    }
}
```

With fstream

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void VMatrix::SaveFile(string _fileName) 
{
    fstream myfile;

    myfile.open("Test.txt", std::ios::out);

    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "*** error: could not open output file\n";
    }

    myfile << "Test";
    myfile.close();
}
```

In both of the examples above, I have tested them by themselves in vs code and they work (They are both just for testing and are not final). I have tested from a blank C++ UWP app and it didn't. Is there file write permissions I can enable somewhere within the project?

Edit - I have found that the programs working directory did not have permissions and I have fixed it but I am still unable to specify a path to anywhere else on the computer to write to, or read from, files.

Comment: You're using a relative path.  Do you know what the current working directory is at that point?  If it's a directory to which you don't have write access, you won't be able to create a file in it.

Comment: The current working directory was set to a weird appx subfolder that didn't have permissions and enabling those permissions fixed it but I still can't write to a file by specifying the directory. It only works to write to that folder. The project directory has permissions and it can't write to it. It can only access files within the APPX directory.

Comment: UWP runs each in an own sandbox, you can't write files outside the sandbox. I'm most case you should use specific UWP API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/fileio-learning-track

Answer (score 0):

For how to read and write files in C++/WinRT UWP, you can refer to the document [UWP Create, write, and read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).

If you want to access files outside the UWP application, you need to use [Filepicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) or [open file access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example). Please note that after using the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, users need to manually open the permission in the App setting.